# how to solve overflowing text

Tags: html, css

Can someone please help me solve the layout frommy pen?
http://codepen.io/Sidney-Dev/pen/ALPgbG

When I start resizing the page,content of the lists start overflowing and I a m failing to figure out what it can be.

I gave a padding  to  the section where I have the table just to see properly how the content overflows.

```
div.tables{
  padding: 0 20px;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing `display: flex` with specific `width` properties.

If you are using `display: flex` on your tables container, stick with `flex: 1` on your tables, so instead of:

```
table{
  width: 50%;
}
```

Go with:

```
table{
  flex: 1;
}
```

Comment: flex:1 will not really responsively.Did you test how it looks through my pen?
If you test you'll  see that the  content in the second table does not respond correctly when you resize the screen

Comment: I have tested this on your Pen, and your overflow problem has been resolved. What do you mean by "`flex: 1` is not responsive"? What it is you are after? The question was regarding overflow...

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the content justification on the parent container so that the elements know how to flex. You also need to set the tables to display in a flexible way.

```
div.tables{
  padding: 0 20px;
  justify-content:center;
}
table {
  display:inline-flex
}
```

Comment: Perhaps  am not following.Please check my pen to see how it overflows.
http://codepen.io/Sidney-Dev/pen/ALPgbG